# Small signal equivalent circuit BJT question

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, signal, bjt

This circuit is two BJT transistors in so called 'darlington configuration'. I want to analyse this circuit for AC signals (where the capacitors are shorts).

[image]

The question is to calculate Delta_V_L/Delta_V_G (sorry I don't know how to use subscripts here)

This is what I think it should be but unfortunately when I plug in the numbers it's not correct. Solution should be Delta_V_L/Delta_V_G= -50.

[image]
Any ideas on how to solve this and is this smallsignal equivalent circuit correct?
Thanks!

Edit: h_ie1 and h_ie2 are the smallsignal model resistances, hence why they aren't on the original circuit

Edit2: I realised that there are different models for small signal analysis, I'm using this one:
[image]

Comment: Try analysing the circuit from a DC (biasing)  perpective first

Comment: Have you try to write a equation? For example for Vin we have  \$ Vin = Ib1 *hie1 + (\beta 1 + 1)*Ib1*hie2  \$ and for Vout \$  Vout = (\beta 1 + 1)*Ib1 * \beta 2 * Rc|R_L \$

Comment: You should use the transconductance gm. Also your first stage equation is completly false, the first stage got a feedback effect from the second input base resistance.

Comment: @JImDearden I already did DC analysis, that was no problem; AC analysis is completely different though

Comment: @Arthur VP I already give you the solution. You do not see it ?

Comment: @Mathieu where do you see a feedback loop?

Comment: @G36 I see now, it is correct indeed, how did u find this? Where does (Beta_1+1) term come from
Thanks!

Comment: I forgot about the "minus" sign in Vout equation. Also notice that Ie = Ib + Ic = Ib + beta*Ib = (beta + 1)*Ib. I simply use KVL and some understanding of how transistor work. Notice that Ib2 = Ib1+Ic1= Ie1 = (beta1 + 1)*Ib1 also Vin = Ib1*hie1+ Ib2*hie2

Comment: @LvW The dependant current source produce a current which is proportionnal to the voltage difference of the base resistance, however here the emitter isn't grounded so the voltage difference of the base resistance is Vg - Ve where Ve is a potential created by the dependant current source which result in a feedback. However in most analysis of the Darlington, people neglect that effect.

Comment: @LvW, emitter degeneration can be analyzed as a negative feedback mechanism (as I'm sure you are already aware).

Comment: OK - I see what you mean. I rather consider the first stage as a common collector configuration (with the dynamic resistance of the B-E path of the 2nd transistor as the gain determining resistance). Therefore I didn`t call it "emitter degeneration" - however, it can be seen this way.

Answer (score 2):

Without using any small-signal equivalent diagram I consider the circuit as a two-stage transistor amplifier: (1) The first stage is in common-collector configuration and (2) the 2nd stage is a clasical common-emitter stage.

- Assuming a DC voltage of 0.6 volts across both B-E diodes it is easy to find the base current IB1 for the first transistor and, hence, all the other three currents (IC1, IB2, IC2) because the current gains are given.
- Applying the relation for the transconductance **gm=Ic/VT** and **rbe=beta/gm** we easily can find the gain values for both stages: **G1=0.5** and **G2=-100**. Hence, the total gain, indeed, is **G=G1*G2=-50.**

(By the way: In a typical/classical Darlington configuration both collector nodes are connected).

Comment: For this circuit it is better to assume 0.7 volts across two B-E junctions. Therefore Ic = 4.95mA; hie1 = 500 Ohms ; Ic2 = 100mA; hie2 = 5 ohm. Also for this type of a connection the voltage gain will be equal 0.5 times the common-emitter stage gain (the second stage).  Av = - 0.5 * gm2 * Rc = 0.5 * 4 Siemens * 25 Ohms = -50. Because Vin splits two Vbe.

Comment: Your result is Ic1=4.95mA and my result was Ic1=5.05 mA. Therefore, the "best" value, perhaps, would be VBE=0.65 volts. In any case, it is an estimate only (and, certainly, both B-E voltages will not be equal.)

Comment: But notice that no matter what what the re'b1 = hie2 where re'b = Vt/Ie. In this case re'b1 = Vt/Ie1 and it is also equal to hie2 = Vt/Ie1 and this is why the first stage gain (emitter-follower) is always equal to 0.5 (G1 = hie2/(re'b1 + hie2)). Therefore vbe1 = vbe2 (from small signal point of view). And this also explain why -0.5*gm2*Rc is true.

Comment: Yes - of course. However, my point was only to mention that both Vbe values (DC) will not be equal. Nevertheless, without any additional information we must assume Vbe1=Vbe2.